# Control front-end javascript from node.js back-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, frontend, backend

I am building a chat app and I want to ask users to input their username. JQuery front-end code slides a form into view (on ready), stores the data into variables and then loads the chat (when enter key or button is pressed). How do I stop that animation until I validate user input on server-side? I am using node.js for backend. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Front-end jQuery:

```js
var nameChoice, roomChoice; //to store user input

var initName = function() {

  nameChoice = $("#init-name input").val(); //save chosen name in nameChoice
  $("#current-name").text("Username: " + nameChoice); //put chosen name in chat header
  $("#init-name").animate(
   {"left" : "-35%"}, 300,
   function() {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
    $("#init-room").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#init-room").animate({"left" : "35%"}, 300);
  });  //remove name form and slide in room form in callback
 } //end initName

var initRoom = function() {
  roomChoice = $("#init-room select").val(); //save chosen room in roomChoice
  $("#current-room").text("Room: " + roomChoice); //put chosen room in chat header
  $("#init-room").animate(
   {"left" : "-35%"}, 300,
   function() {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
    $("#chat-main").removeClass("hidden");
  }); //remove room form and show page in callback
 } //end initRoom

var btnHover = function() {
 $(".btn-form").hover(
  function() {
   $(this).stop().animate(
   {
    backgroundColor : "#FFBD7A"
   }, 300);
  },
  function() {
   $(this).stop().animate(
   {
    backgroundColor : "white"
   }, 300);
  });
}

var init = function() {

 $("#init-name").removeClass("hidden").animate({"left" : "35%"}, 300); //slide in name form
 
 $(document).keydown(function(event) { //submit choice on enter key
  if (event.which === 13) {
   if (!$("#init-name").hasClass("hidden")) { //if user is choosing name
    event.preventDefault();
    initName(); //call initName function
   }

   if (!$("#init-room").hasClass("hidden")) { //if user is choosing room
    event.preventDefault();
    initRoom(); //call initRoom function
   }
  }
 }); //end enter key submission

 $("#init-name .btn-form").click(initName);
 $("#init-room .btn-form").click(initRoom);

 btnHover(); 
} //end init
$(document).ready(init);
```

I'm still learning node, so no back-end code yet...

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: But to answer you question in the general sense, when the user hits the enter key, send the data to the back end (AJAX) and have it return a response of either success or failure, then continue with loading the chat if a success comes back, else keep the user on the form.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon - and so I did :)

Comment: Alright, now, where is the call that sends the user name to the server?

Comment: Well, it should be in another file... should it? In server.js or something like that? I was going to keep the animations with style and sending data with backend... is that wrong thinking?

Comment: It can be in another file, but THIS code needs to make a call to the back end asking it to validate the user, you can achieve this with jQuery Ajax.  If there is no backend then you don't really have a chat application, you just have a page that looks like chat should exist there; since you need to validate users in some manner.

Comment: I recommend looking at these: https://github.com/IgorAntun/node-chat , https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat, and http://socket.io/get-started/chat/  you can see how they implemented chat. This is really not about your question, but next steps.

Answer (score 2):

rough code for this ...

```
$http.post("/login", {"username":username, "password": password}).then(function(response) {

   console.log("success - do animation here");

}.catch(function(response) {

    console.log("failure a non 2xx HTTP response - handle error here");
});
```

This code is crude since the http request should prob be in a service, also I have not linted this code, BUT you should get the general IDEA!

APOLOGIES THIS IS ANGULAR, JQUERY WAS ASKED FOR ... HERE GOES ...

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/login",
  data: { username: username, password: password }
})
.then(
  function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    console.log("success - do animation here");
  }, 
  function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    console.log("failure a non 2xx HTTP response - handle error here");
  }
);
```

Never tried this in Jquery before but the docs suggest this approach.
Check the docs at ...

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Thanks

**Edit**: in case promise based jQuery code not available:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/login",
  data: { username: username, password: password }
})
// for older versions of jQuery, replace .done and .fail with .success and .error
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    console.log("success - do animation here");
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    console.log("failure a non 2xx HTTP response - handle error here");
});
```

Comment: Are you assuming Angular here? along with promises being available? But the general idea applies. Can you also provide a jQuery Ajax example?

Comment: I do apologise, I'm so used to answering Angular questions! I've provided the comparative jQuery solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and examples. I have just one more question: should I just call jQuery functions that I defined (initName, initRoom and so on) instead of `console.log("success - do animation here");`, or not?

Comment: sorry for delay in reply, Christmas and all :) Yeah replace the console.log statement with the code that triggers your animations